# Disable the create button

Tags: javascript, module

I need to disable the create button when adding a new card. I needed to disable it for the meantime until the user added the data to the field. Any idea? below is my project. Still new to it in web dev.

Thanks!

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212) — the same applies to “Any idea?” —, and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the `object.values of the field, and do your onclick function:

```
if (val !=="") {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with javascript for example:

```
var name_of_place = document.GetElementById('something');
var img_lnk  = document.GetElementById('img-example');
bar btn_create = document.querySelector('btn');

if(name_of_place == "" || img_lnk == ""){
  btn_create.disabled = true
}
else{
 btn_create.disabled = false 
}
```